# Turn off Error AND Usage Reporting SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

Unfortunately, SQL Server usage internet bandwidth and us activity in SQL, for R&D. You can find in your server, this service is called: **SQL Server error and usage**.

This service is active without any privacy permission, in installation process.

[image]

If you don't like this future can be **turn off** this activity. Like below:

[image]

But, I have a problem in SQL Server 2019: we use two SQL instances on one server - both SQL Server 2017 and SQL Server 2019.

I can turn-off SQL Server 2017 error and usage reporting service as shown in the screenshots, but when I open error and usage reporting service for SQL Server 2019 in a cmd window, and then close automatically and don't show anything:

[image]

How to turn off error and usage reporting SQL Server 2019 now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are registry keys you can edit, see [Configure usage and diagnostic data collection for SQL Server (CEIP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/usage-and-diagnostic-data-configuration-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#set-registry-subkeys-on-the-server). Alternatively, there's a thread over on [Microsoft's Azure forums](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39081679-sql-server-error-and-usage-report-does-not-work) that suggests this behavior is caused by some sort of misconfiguration in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared\SqlWtsn.exe.config` file and either renaming that file to SqlWtsn.exe.config.OLD or editing the contents of the file make fix the issue. I can say that the few times I've encountered this issue, renaming SqlWtsn.exe.config worked for me.